# Java mulithreading - Is there a way to synchonize/lock a specific value in a map for both reads and writes?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, parallel-processing

I am wanting to implement a topo-sort algorithm that can be done in parallel over a graph in Java using threads. Specifically, the algorithm found in this paper [here](https://watermark.silverchair.com/26-4-293.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAkMwggI_BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggIwMIICLAIBADCCAiUGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMsElG9SFz1AoKlAIGAgEQgIIB9qUsjvbgigYAPIgaZGM3jrbdVqvXu_VnBoi2tGW9WQPTvF82VfwJqwOno2tQlF_kmK8FhRgx1BtM-1mV_FDdhHbCJgkzE297k4UwqIx4ua6BxYbR1AG_1pJufAbLCQL5qUluEyFWwFKldMZSeBeD81oNGMgZ5CnwGpr4sfm9Yn3xCrgKeeLjgizgv7g-AlAIiDBkaJHfc8pz65YLCmn0gpxkIsZpblSMZx2HbfjmznNwXFidTibKq25b5Zg3q9rNkgGyvISCj4ZGkAJf1imzbBYUm-RK0iuNDHGRAGITy4MF0OdbIeSmBjIlhHkyqD0xWUWUCC71NwZO6ZbGAAxw1ubi4WHDE6AV_cgaS1E1oaXFypJWSvDYs8Nd2o68IP7RdZtlcQqMFklnay797jlKUbXNQ88cOfUbE4pCRDCfzCcgRe2jI6ZoO5x-3GFKijWSrkIcauHao7iH4oroHDgl2buaY6yS0AlIBllhn7dADWcLO6CldySv1d0wdGXv3YTJbo0FR4g95QqRDHTphTuNp3lvJLcJACMhWNLDftZdpc5I4aVCyryKKTuFzy6excdV5_ceQiZbWXPr3sAmtUOvXsVf-acJzATi4f_NjtdSJhhm84tOwyZXy0zAzwFCbWQz1xuJzAJRw6nzA2EpsR-Qn0ZKiZzdwt4).

The important part of this algorithm for this question is that the schedule value we are storing for each node is updated as follows: if a thread comes across a node in the graph, it will read its current value. If the thread has a higher value, it will replace it and continue along. Otherwise it will stop there.

I need to be able to do the write and read for a specific node in one atomic operation. I want to represent the value as a value in a map against an int key id (for each node). However, from what I see the synchronization techniques for Maps in java seem to either only lock on writes, or lock the whole map. If the whole map is locked, performance may as well be single threaded. If the reads are not locked, I can get the wrong behavior.

My goal is to lock only on a specific index. If two threads want to read and update different nodes, that is okay, but if two threads come across the same node, I need to make sure that each operation of `read -> check -> update or stop` happens atomically. The specific case I am looking to avoid is:

```
Thread_1 (val 5) read g_1 -> value is 3, trigger update
Thread_2 (val 4) read g_1 -> value is 3, trigger update
Thread_1 (val 5) lock and update g_1 -> g_1 value is 5
Thread_2 (val 4) lock and update g_1 -> g_1 value is 4
```

instead, I'm looking to do:

```
Thread_1 (val 5) lock g_1
Thread_2 (val 4) wait for g_1
Thread_1 (val 5) read g_1 -> value is 3, update g_1 -> g_1 value is 5
Thread_1 (val 5) release g_1
Thread_2 (val 4) lock g_1
Thread_2 (val 4) read g_1 -> value is 5, do nothing
Thread_2 (val 4) release g_1
```

Comment: Don't use URL shorteners.

Comment: Can you obtain a lock on the `Map.Entry`?

Comment: I apologize for the URL shortener. The URL is massive and frankly not that relevant to the question, but I didn't want to take up 5 lines with a link.

Comment: @antonig StackOverflow uses markdown, so nobody will ever see those 5 lines if you simply format the link using SO's tools. Just highlight the "this paper" string, click the link icon, and paste that 5-line URL. Done. I'd edit your question to show you, but of course the shortened URL is a dead link. Just one of many reasons URL shorteners should never be used outside of Twitter.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese no, `Map.Entry`s can be thought of as views on the data. Locking one does nothing to the `Map` itself. None of Java's native collections are thread safe other than the ones specifically documented as such. I.e. the ones with names that start with `Concurrent`, or ones that you create using one of the `Collections.synchronized*` wrappers. Of course the wrapped collections use the simplistic locking scheme that OP observed would kill parallelism for this problem.

Comment: @antonig Just FYI, my answer will trigger updates in the way you asked, but you still have to be careful in your update code. For example, if node 1 has value 1, thread 3 could trigger an update, then immediately afterwards thread 5 could do the same. Since it sounds like your updates are handled in a different thread, `triggerUpdate` and/or your update code needs to handle this case correctly.

Comment: @adam So can you not have a block that is `synchronized` on a `Map.Entry`?

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese, of course you can block on a `Map.Entry` just like you can block on any `Object`, but that won't prevent another thread from making changes to the map or even that particular key/value pair. `Map.Entry` docs: " the behavior of a map entry is undefined if the backing map has been modified after the entry was returned by the iterator, except through the setValue operation on the map entry." If you're lucky you'll get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, but you could also just get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your keyset is static then you can simply use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) values. You could use [`compareAndSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet-int-int-) like this:

```
atomicValue = map.get(key);
while (true) {
    value = atomicValue.get();
    if (value < myThreadNumber) {
        if (value.compareAndSet(value, myThreadNumber) {
            // successfully increased the thread number
            triggerUpdate();
            break;
        } // else value update failed, loop back to try again.
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) which does not lock the entire map. Java 8 added a lot of concurrency methods that make what you want relatively straight forward. For example, if your trigger code is relatively fast then you can simply use [`compute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
map.compute(key, (key, value) -> {
    if (value < myThreadNumber) {
        triggerUpdate();
        return myThreadNumber;
    }
    return value; // no changes
})
```

Of course you can always construct a value type that pairs your `int` with a lock, but that's only useful for school work. In practice locks are so expensive you definitely don't want any in your inner loops.

Comment: In your example, you should use `computeIfPresent` when doing `value < myThreadNumber` unconditionally. Otherwise, when using `compute`, you should first test for `value == null` and initialize it with the intended initial value.

Comment: Hi Adam, this does look like what I need, thank you!. I saw your other comment, ```triggerUpdate()``` is quite literally just updating the value of the int stored in the map, and can (and should) happen synchronously after the read on the same thread. I believe I can do this in this code block and it should work perfectly well. Thank you!

Comment: @Holger of course you're right, but in this case I'd argue `compute` is safer. The problem doesn't specify what should happen when the key doesn't exist, presumably because some initial step populates the map. If a null value is looked up somehow anyway then my `compute` code would throw, alerting OP that something unexpected happened. `computeIfPresent` would simply do nothing, which implies that null keys should be ignored and I'm pretty sure that's not what the algorithm calls for.

Comment: If the initialization step is trivial, then potentially your suggested `value == null` check could potentially let OP skip that step altogether.